# "Extract To..." gone after updating from 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: upgrade, 16.10, archive, pcmanfm, extract

I recently updated my LXDE from Xenial Xerus to Yakkety Yakk.

After the upgrade, I no longer see the Extraction-related context menu items for compressed files (e.g. rar) in PCManFM. Why is that? How can I bring them back?

Answer (score 0):

As for as unrar, since the ubuntu/lubuntu 16.04.1 lts update, I have had to use the unrar e /home/user/downloads/filename.rar (I have been running 14.04 for a while now) have you tried updating or reinstalling PCmanfm? I think xarchiver comes default with ubuntu, is that installed on your installation, find out using apt-get, but i have never been able to open rar files w/ xarchiver